# Linear dependence of a sequence

Tags: vector-spaces

I know how to check linear dependence of two funtions, but what about a sequence of n functions? I'm unsure how to write it.

Example: ln(x), ln(2x), ..., ln(nx)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#The_Wronskian_and_linear_independence

Comment: What specifically is your obstacle: understanding how to check linear dependence of $n$ vectors in a vector space in general, or understanding how to apply that method when the elements of the vector space are functions?

Comment: the first question